# is this right way to use std::upper_bound and std::lower_bound?

Tags: c++, search, stl

I have a sorted vector of pair objects. I am going to use `std::upper_bound` and `std::lower_bound` to find all elements such that `(data>=a) && (data<b)`. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


using namespace std;

struct comp_lower
{
  comp_lower() {}
  bool operator()(const pair<double, unsigned> &data, const double &bound) const
  {
    return data.first<bound;
  }
};

struct comp_upper
{
  comp_upper() {}
  bool operator()(const double &bound, const pair<double, unsigned> &data) const
  {
    return bound <= data.first;
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  std::vector< std::pair<double, unsigned> > sortData;

  // sort the data manually based on the first entry
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-5, 1) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-4.5, 10) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-4 , 19) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-4 , 2) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-3.5 , 28) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-3.5 , 11) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-3 , 37) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-3 , 20) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-3 , 3) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-2.5 , 12) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-2.5 , 29) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-2 , 38) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-2 , 21) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-2 , 4) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-1.5 , 30) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-1.5 , 13) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-1 , 39) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-1 , 22) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-1 , 5) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-0.5 , 31) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(-0.5 , 14) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(0 , 6) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(0 , 23) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(0 , 40) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(0.5 , 32) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(0.5 , 15) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(1 , 41) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(1 , 24) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(1 , 7) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(1.5 , 33) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(1.5 , 16) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(2 , 42) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(2 , 25) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(2 , 8) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(2.5 , 17) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(2.5 , 34) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(3 , 43) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(3 , 26) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(3 , 9) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(3.5 , 35) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(3.5 , 18) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(4 , 44) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(4 , 27) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(4.5 , 36) );
  sortData.push_back( make_pair(5 , 45) );

  double a = -4.1;
  double b = -3.0;

  vector< pair<double, unsigned> >::iterator lower = std::lower_bound(sortData.begin(), sortData.end(), a, comp_lower());
  vector< pair<double, unsigned> >::iterator upper = std::upper_bound(sortData.begin(), sortData.end(), b, comp_upper());

  cout << (lower->first) << "," << (lower->second) << "  [" << a << "]" <<   endl;
  cout << (upper->first) << "," << (upper->second) <<  "  [" << b << "]" << endl << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Here I am searching all elements with the first entries greater than or equal to -4.1 and less than -3. It should return (-4 , 19) and (-3.5, 11) but it returns (0,0) and (-3, 37). I think I used upper_bound and lower_bound wrong but I failed to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why it does not return (-4, 19) as the first result: You have the parameter type wrong in comp_lower. The `bound` parameter should be `double`, not unsigned.

Why it does not return (-3.5, 11) as the second result: Your code says `double b = -3.0`, even though your problem description states -3.9.

Still, this is not quite correct. Both `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` return the *first* element of a sequence that fulfills certain rule, so neither is directly suitable to the task of finding the upper limit you need. However, if you simply take the preceding element, you will get the correct result:

```
vector< pair<double, unsigned> >::iterator upper = 
    std::upper_bound(sortData.begin(), sortData.end(), b, comp_upper()) - 1;
```

And, of course, you have to check if upper_bound has returned the first element of the sequence so that the iterator won't go out of bounds with the decrement.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It takes me quite a long to figure out what's going on because the logical mistake doesn't reflect in the compile. Anyway, I fix the bugs but still won't get the right answer. Now I am searching all elements in >=-4.1 && < -3.0 (excluding -3.0). I expect to get (-4,19) and (-3.5, 11) but I get (-4, 19) and (-3, 37)

Comment: Yes, sorry. I missed the actual problem in logic when fixing the typos. I have edited the answer to contain the real solution as well.